# Query in nested document in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Here is my mongoose schema:

```
const chapterSchema = mongoose.Schema({
title: {
    type: String
},
number: {
    type: Number
}
})

const bookSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    title: {
        type: String
    },
    author: {
        type: String
    },
    chapters: [chapterSchema]
})

const Book = mongoose.model('Book', bookSchema)
module.exports = Book
```

Here is my database:

```
{
"_id": "5f56f8e66a7eee227c1acc0a",
"title": "Book1",
"author": "Author1",
"chapters": [{
    "_id": "5f56fa47a78fbf03cc32d16d",
    "title": "Chapter1",
    "number": 1
}, {
    "_id": "5f56fad10820300de031317f",
    "title": "Chapter2",
    "number": 2,
}]
}
```

I want to find a specific chapter from the *chapters* array by it's id. So, I wrote this code:

```
router.get('/:id', async function (req, res) {
try {
    const id = req.params.id
    await Book.findById(id, function (err, chapter) {
        res.render('chapter.hbs', {
            chapter: chapter
        })
    })
} catch (error) {
    res.redirect('/')
}
})
```

According to the chapter id, I want this result:

```
{
    "_id": "5f56fa47a78fbf03cc32d16d",
    "title": "Chapter1",
    "number": 1
}
```

or

```
{
    "_id": "5f56fad10820300de031317f",
    "title": "Chapter2",
    "number": 2,
}
```

What should I do to find a specific chapter using it's id?

Comment: you can try `await Book.findOne({"chapters._id": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id)})`

Comment: @turivishal It doesn't work.

Comment: why i have not replied here? because you have not provided what is not working, you need to show what are you getting and not getting, we can't understand the problem when you say *It doesn't work* || *This solution doesn't work* || *Not solved my problem* . this way no one will understand your problem and you will not get any proper answer.

Comment: I don't get the expected result.

Comment: yes then reply them with details i am getting this from your answer and not getting expected, so they can re correct and update you.

Comment: lets debug, are you getting result when you execute this `await Book.find()`? second in collection all chapters _id are object id ?

Comment: @turivishal after using `await Book.find(function (err, chapter) {
        res.send(chapter)
    })` I get the whole collection as `[{
"_id": "5f56f8e66a7eee227c1acc0a",
"title": "Book1",
"author": "Author1",
"chapters": [{
    "_id": "5f56fa47a78fbf03cc32d16d",
    "title": "Chapter1",
    "number": 1
}, {
    "_id": "5f56fad10820300de031317f",
    "title": "Chapter2",
    "number": 2,
}]
}]`

Comment: yes, each chapter's id is _id.

Answer (score 0):

You are searching on Book using findById of chapters Id, it will not give result since it is not Book Id,

You will need to use `$elemMatch` for this

check this [Querying for Object in Mongoose Sub Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37666138/querying-for-object-in-mongoose-sub-array) for reference

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the [aggregate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/index.html) function.

```
router.get('/:id', async function (req, res) {
  try {
    const id = req.params.id
    await Books.aggregate([
      {
        $project: {
          title: 1,
          author: 1,
          chapters: {
            $filter: {
              input: "$chapters",
              as: "chapter",
              cond: {
                $eq: [
                  "$$chapter.id", id
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ])
  } catch (error) {
    res.redirect('/')
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `aggregate()` function,

- `$match` your condition
- `$filter` to get specific chapter id
- `$replaceWith` to replace chapter in root

```
const id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id);

let chapter = await Book.aggregate([
  { $match: { "chapters._id": id } },
  {
    $replaceWith: {
      $arrayElemAt: [
        {
          $filter: {
            input: "$chapters",
            cond: { $eq: ["$$this._id", id] }
          }
        },
        0
      ]
    }
  }
]);

console.log(chapter);
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/koWxkKqLhsW)

Comment: Thanks! Now I am getting something. But this is an array `[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5f56fad10820300de031317f"),
    "number": 2,
    "title": "Chapter2"
  }
]`. I want only `{
    "_id": ObjectId("5f56fad10820300de031317f"),
    "number": 2,
    "title": "Chapter2"
  }`

Comment: @TahsinAlMahi Is there something in the provided answer that you believe does not address your question? If so then please comment on the answer to clarify what exactly needs to be addressed that has not. If it does in fact answer the question you asked then please note to [Accept your Answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to the questions you ask