# Query an Array of Embedded Documents with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Here is my document with embedded documents:

```
{
    "_id": "5f56f8e66a7eee227c1acc0a",
    "title": "Book1",
    "author": "Author1",
    "chapters": [{
        "_id": "5f56fa47a78fbf03cc32d16d",
        "title": "Chapter1",
        "number": 1
    }, {
        "_id": "5f56fad10820300de031317f",
        "title": "Chapter2",
        "number": 2,
    }]
    }
```

To find a specific *chapter* from the *chapters* array by it's `id` I wrote this code:

```
router.get('/:id', async function (req, res) {
try {
    const id = req.params.id
    await Book.findById(id, function (err, chapter) {
        console.log(chapter)
    })
} catch (error) {
    res.redirect('/')
}
})
```

I found an empty array `[]`. But I expect this result:

```
{
    "_id": "5f56fa47a78fbf03cc32d16d",
    "title": "Chapter1",
    "number": 1
}
```

What should I do to find the specific *chapter* from the *chapters* array by it's `id`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Query in nested document in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63787633/query-in-nested-document-in-mongodb) you asked similar question second time.

Comment: @turivishal No. Not a single solution solved my problem. Morever, there is a little change in this problem.

Comment: I can not see any change, the requirement is same, its not the way to ask same question every time, just the reason of not solving you problem, thats why provided a feature called accept answer, we can understand you have not resolved your problem, if its minor change then you can edit your question any time, you can  delete any one question from both of them.

Answer (score 0):

```
router.get('/:id', async function (req, res) {
try {
  const id = req.params.id
  // this is what you need to change
  await Book.find({ "chapters._id": id }, function (err, chapter) {
    console.log(chapter)
  })
} catch (error) {
  res.redirect('/')
}
})
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the question, in order to get a specific `chapter` from the `chapters` array you can use [Aggregate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/aggregate.html#aggregate_Aggregate)

```js
const result = await Book.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "chapters._id": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id),
    },
  },
  { $unwind: "$chapters" },
  {
    $match: {
      "chapters._id": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id),
    },
  },
  { $replaceWith: "$chapters" },
]);
console.log(result);
```

If the chapter `id` is unique throughout the collection, then the result will be an array with one `chapter` document inside it

Sample result:

```js
[
  {
    _id: "5f56fa47a78fbf03cc32d16d",
    title: "Chapter1",
    number: 1,
  },
];
```

Comment: Your solution provided the result you showed, but not solved my problem.

Comment: @TahsinAlMahi As per my understanding what you need is a chapter from chapters array for which the id matches. Add a sample expected result JSON to the question

Comment: I have updated the answer, the result will be array since the `Arregate` method returns an array. You can check if whether the array is empty and if not take the first element to get your expected result