# mongoDB - get object from subArray by id

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express

so i have the following document in mongoDB:

```
const Categories = [
{
    _id: 's654fs54s6d4f'
    title: 'category 1',
    SubCats: [
        {
            _id: 'jhgfsf68746'
            name: 'subcat 1',
            image: '/assets/images/vr-box-6203301_1920.jpg',
        },
        {
            _id: 'vb40n5b4vn'
            name: 'subcat 2',
            image: '/assets/images/galaxy-s20_highlights_kv_00.jpg',
        },
    ]
},
]
```

and  this is the schema:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose'

const Catschema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    image: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
})

const CategorySchema = mongoose.Schema(
    {
        title: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
        SubCats: [Catschema]
    },
    {
        timestamps: true,
    }
)

const Category = mongoose.model('Category', CategorySchema)

export default Category
```

i can get 'category 1' by its id using:

```
const getCategoryById = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const category = await Category.findById(req.params.id)
})
```

and the whole array would be the output.

my question is how to get object 'subcat 1' by its id 'jhgfsf68746'.

Desired output:

```
{
  _id: 'jhgfsf68746'
  name: 'subcat 1',
  image: '/assets/images/vr-box-6203301_1920.jpg',
},
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37666138/querying-for-object-in-mongoose-sub-array

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure which field is the `default mongodb key` in your example, but here is how you can solve it, just make sure which once is correct for you `_id` or `id`. Also, I've hardcoded the stings

```
User.findOne({_id: 's654fs54s6d4f'})
  .select({ 
    SubCats: {
      $elemMatch: {_id: 'jhgfsf68746'}
    }
  })
```

Comment: Except `'jhgfsf68746'` is not a valid MongoDB _id, it's a custom string (bad practice from OP), so `mongoose.ObjectId('jhgfsf68746')` will likely crash with a validation error

Comment: Indeed, thanks @JeremyThille. I will update the answer

Comment: @Eduard thank you for the answer. the id 'jhgfsf68746' is just a dummy id for the sake of positng the question. im using correct id format in mongoDB.  and i tried the code that you provided. and im getting `{"_id":"s654fs54s6d4f","SubCats":[{"_id":"jhgfsf68746","name":"subcat 1","image":"/assets/images/vr-box-6203301_1920.jpg"}]}`  instead of `[{"_id":"jhgfsf68746","name":"subcat 1","image":"/assets/images/vr-box-6203301_1920.jpg"}]}`